# jQuery ajax function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("a[rel=profile]").live('click',function() {
            var profileURL = $(this).attr('href')         
            $.ajax({
                url: profileURL,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    $("#profile").html(data);
                    $("#profile").fadeIn();
                  }
            });                                   
            return false;
        })
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code, when I click the link with `rel=profile` it fires the `alert()` with the remote URL content but doesn't load it into the `div` and then `fadeIn()`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That all depends on what `data` is expected to be. What are you getting back?

Comment: Its the content of the remove URL...

Comment: I'd probably use the load extension for this like pixelbobby has suggested but maybe you're just missing `dataType: "html"` from your ajax declaration.

Comment: Quick note (little off topic), the above code will throw an error in IE. This is because there needs to be a semicolon at the end. The reason it will still work in other browsers is because they have semicolon insertion and I believe that IE does not (including IE9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just try something like this instead.  See the API for the [`Load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.  You can also pass it a `callback` so you can do something after the load is complete like so:

```
$("a[rel=profile]").live('click', function() {
    $('#profile').load( 
        $(this).attr('href'), 
        function(){ $('#profile').fadeIn();});

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I was using load() originally but it was running very clunkily, it seemed to work fine using $.ajax...

Comment: It actually seems to have fixed itself after a good refresh :) but this is the best answer of the bunch.

Comment: @Chris You might be interested in seeing this [Load](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=jQuery.fn.load).  Basically the load function is just a wrapper around a set of defaults on the `$.ajax` function.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance @Chris.  Happy venturing w/ jQuery.  It's a pretty gnarly ride :)

Comment: Thanks @Nicky thats really interesting, seeing the behind code gives this some well needed perspective! and @Pixelbobby cheers for your help mate, have streamlined the code and have actually ended up using your load with callback now :)